# Firefox cut off portion of text near page end when printing to PDF

Tags: firefox, pdf, printing, print-to-pdf

I'm trying to print to PDF a page with Firefox.

But in the resulting PDF, a portion of text is cut off near the end of the page.

This happens both with "Margin: Standard" and "Margins: None".

How can I fix it?

Here is a screenshot of what's happening:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think I finally managed to solve it.

There was a "navigation bar" (totally white) with a larger z-index than the text, with a fixed position near the bottom of the page, that was hiding the text behind it.

I hid this navigation bar with the following CSS:

```
div.viewer-navigation {
    display: none !important;
    width: 0% !important;
    height: 0% !important;
    z-index: -1 !important;
    position: static !important;
}
```

Notice how I also applied a negative z-index (to place it behind the text, it was `2` before, placing it above the text) and restored its position to `static` (it was `fixed` before).

In order to find out how the printed page is rendered, from Firefox open the "Web Developer Tools" (Hamburger menu -> More Tools -> Web Developer Tools, or Ctrl-Shift-I), and in the "Inspector Tab", in the center pane click on the "Toggle print media simulation for the page" button (it's in the top right corner, it looks like a paper page):

[image]